# Contentful.Csharp Nuget Package in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, nuget

So I've successfully uploaded the nuget package into my azure function, but it keeps giving me this error:

> "The type or namespace name 'ContentfulClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I've installed the nuget package from a project.json file.

This is my code:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;


private static HttpClient httpClient;
private static ContentfulClient contentfulClient;
private static ContentfulClient contentfulPreviewClient;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, 
 TraceWriter log){
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    httpClient = new HttpClient();
    contentfulClient = new ContentfulClient(httpClient, 
   "f802e4676d16fc1476580e4a50c8f3b180b875eaffad0680a55139f3338d5ac3","i6w3gtjaaewo");
    contentfulPreviewClient = new ContentfulClient(httpClient, 
   "e9da3ff45bc38a213c41ac768732c0ac75df5c453a2ed651bfd946cb5f226c5f", "i6w3gtjaaewo", true);

     log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    // parse query parameter
     string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
    .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
    .Value;

  // Get request body
  dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

  // Set name to query string or body data
  name = name ?? data?.name;

   return name == null
    ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on 
    the query string or in the request body")
    : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
}
```

Comment: Well I don't see a `using` directive... are you just missing `using Contentful.Core;`?

Comment: ``installed the nuget package from a project.json file`` Can you share the details of your project.json file? Please check if installing Package contentful.csharp is success in Azure function logs.

Comment: I have installed the nuget package via the project.json file.

Answer (score 0):

So I've found a way around this by referencing the direct dll inside the nuget package. It turns out that Azure functions does not support libraries targeting higher than NetStandard 1.3 at the moment. Very soon an update will be released to fix this issue. You can follow the conversation here: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/98